# Bootstrap Touchspin Change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

my code doesn't seem to work on change event when I use the touchspin buttons, but if I change something in the input field it works.

Code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    function updatePrice()
    {
        //Function stuff here
    }

    $(document).on("change, keyup", "#input1", updatePrice);
});
</script>

<input name="input1" type="text">

<script>
$("input[name='input1']").TouchSpin({
    verticalbuttons: true
}).on('touchspin.on.startspin', function () {updatePrice();});
</script>
```

Comment: Put all your scripts in the ready function. What do you mean by "if I change something". What's something?

Comment: If I write something in the input field it works. But if I use the touchspin it doesn't work. So this doesn't work `.on('touchspin.on.startspin', function () {updatePrice();});`

Answer (score 0):

Take function updatePrice() out of $(document).ready.

Hope it helps.